# Laravel routing structure

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have problem with Laravel routing structure, I need to add or remove some controllers in my projects, if I want to have a core in my projects and then extends to other projects from my core then what should I do with routing in larval? For example, my core may consist of this controllers:

```
userController
groupConroller
messageController
```

Then I want to extend a project from this core that doesn't contain `messageController`, if I want to do this in laravel I should go to the Route file and remove routing to `messageController` but if this controllers number increasing, then this add or removes from `Route` files is not seems good, by the way I'm new in larval maybe your simple answers help me.

Comment: also, just a tip... Most laravel developers uppercase both words in the Controller, so UserController, GroupController, MessageController, etc.   Not necessary, but you'll be on the same page as many devs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try creating a ServiceProvider. In the boot() function of ServiceProvider, you can register your routes. Then you just have to add one line to you config.php file where you declare service providers.

Look up laravel service providers for more info.